# От того или оттого, и где поставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, слитно-раздельно

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном случае надо писать "оттого" или "от того"? И нужна ли запятая перед "что"? Текст: "Ты замечательный друг! Я думаю, все твои друзья должны быть счастливы (от)того (,) что у них есть ты"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты замечательный друг! Я думаю, все твои друзья должны быть счастливы **оттого, что** у них есть ты (расчленение союза).

Составной союз ОТТОГО ЧТО, слитное написание приставки ОТ. Союз может расчленяться или не расчленяться, запятая ставится один раз.

**Правило: следует различать парные варианты с разной грамматикой:**

1) **союз ОТТОГО ЧТО** со значением причины:

Я от жизни смертельно устал, ничего от нее не приемлю, но люблю мою бедную землю, **оттого что** иной не видал (нерасчлененный союз). Анна просыпалась **оттого, что** в окно светило солнце (расчлененный союз).

2) Предлог +  указательное слово в сложноподчиненном предложении:

Многое зависит **от того**, что он скажет.  Это местоименно-определительное придаточное, предложное управление: зависит (от чего?) - от того.
Другой тип придаточного: указательное слово "от того" в главном предложении и союзное слово "что" в придаточном предложении.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но в приведенных примерах к  правилу ведь нет варианта "оттого, что". Там либо "оттого что" (слитно, но без запятой - в пункте 1), либо "от того, что" (раздельно, с запятой - в пункте 2). А пункты 3 и 4 уже немного о другом. Простите, вы не могли бы объяснить, почему тогда в моем варианте "оттого, что". Если не затруднит. Я просто не вполне поняла.

Comment: Я исправила ответ. Парный вариант составляют причинный союз  ОТТОГО, ЧТО и  сочетание предложной формы указательного слова  ОТ ТОГО и союзного слова ЧТО. Это разный тип придаточных. В вашем случае значение причины.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь поняла.

Answer (score 2):

**Ты замечательный друг! Я думаю, все твои друзья должны быть счастливы оттого, что у них есть ты.**

В данном предложении союз ОТТОГО ЧТО расчленен (т.е. запятая стоит между частями союза), чтобы подчеркнуть, что на первую часть союза падает логическое ударение. Подробнее на см. на Грамоте: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3